# Cannot use RSpec (rspec: command not found)

Tags: ruby, installation, rspec, homebrew

So I installed the newest version of Ruby:

```
ruby 3.0.0p0 (2020-12-25 revision 95aff21468) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

By following these steps:

```
brew install ruby
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I needed to change the Path so that I could use the newest version of Ruby since if not, whenever I did

```
ruby -v
```

It would just take into account the default ruby version I had installed in my MAC:

```
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
```

Everything works great but I want to install RSpec, so I do:

```
gem install rspec
```

This is what I get:

```
Successfully installed rspec-3.10.0
Parsing documentation for rspec-3.10.0
Done installing documentation for rspec after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But once I check the version:

```
rspec --version
```

This is what I get:

```
-bash: rspec: command not found
```

I have uninstalled ruby with brew and installed it again and restarted the terminal but to no avail. Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Comment: Do you have `rspec` in your Gemfile? you need it to run the `rspec` in there (`under group :development, :test`)  to be able to run it on a project

Comment: @MarkJad you can run `rspec` if you have it installed globally also

Comment: is your gem's bin file in `PATH`? Check `echo $PATH` in the console

Comment: yes true it should be global but in your case, I think this is an issue caused by installing ruby via brew and not a ruby manager, have you tried installing ruby via rbenv? also can you try running `bundle exec rspec` and let me know if it works?

Comment: Thank you very much everyone! as Mark Jad said, it was because I installed ruby via brew. What I did was uninstall it and install it via RVM and it worked! Is rbenv better than rvm? Thanks!

Comment: @jose.gp there is not an easy answer around which is better - It really comes down to your own preference, if I were to sums this up i would say: RVM is easy/faster to install, has a lot of features and it includes built-in Ruby installation mechanism.
Rbenv is lightweight, it's more developer-friendly(working with multiple projects that have different ruby version is easier), unlike rvm it has a dedicated plugin for Ruby installation mechanism.  -- my own preference is rbenv as I like more lightweight managers and I work on multiple projects with different ruby versions

Comment: @jose.gp can you please write as an answer a short summary of what you did to solve this issue, so that this question doesn't stay in the unanswered state forever. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that installing Ruby via Home Brew was giving some problems when trying to run RSpec so I uninstalled it and installed it again via RVM. Although, as @Mskha said, Rbenv could also be a possible option.